# Laravel Recursive Map

Tags: laravel

I need to implement a recursive map function in Laravel. My data looks like this.

[image]

If all_children is empty then I will stop calling the recursive...

My code looks like this, but it doesn't work...

```
public function mapRecursive($model){

    return collect($model)->map(function($val, $key){
        if($key == 'accessables'){
            return $val->accessables;
        }
        if($key == 'all_children'){
            if (count($val->allChildren > 1)){
                $this->mapRecursive($val->allChildren);
            }
        }
    });


}
```

I don't really know how to do it... If you have idea your help is appreciated.

Comment: I think i can answer it, since it a little more than a straight forward thing i will answer it when i get home from work in 6 hours or so. Main thing you are misusing the key attribute, does not work like that, but i also think the approach is making it a bit harder than it should.

Comment: Thanks... I've been trying on this to solve it on my own but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your time...Here is my simple solution.

```
public function mapRecursive($array) {
        $result = [];
        foreach ($array as $item) {
            $result[] = $item['accessables'];
            $result = array_merge($result, $this->mapRecursive($item['allChildren']));
        }
        return array_filter($result);
    }
```

and it works...

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this?

```
if (!(isset($val->allChildren)))
{
  break;
}
```

Comment: My code won't actually work because it's just map function and it will return the `accessables`. Now the problem is how can I call the `allChildren`.

Comment: In javascript it is like this... `var array = res.data.menus
        const result = []
        const cb = (e) => {
          result.push({
            accessables: e.accessables
          })
          e.all_children && e.all_children.forEach(cb)
        }
        array.forEach(cb)

        console.log(result)` and it works...

Comment: I suppose your problem is with syntax and accessing data then if you can code it well in another language.